# Getting results between two dates in PostgreSQL including those two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two dates , I want to display all records in those two dates including those dates.

How can i write query in PostgreSQL,

I have found

```
SELECT *
   FROM mytable
  WHERE (start_date, end_date) OVERLAPS ('2012-01-01'::DATE, '2012-04-12'::DATE);
```

Here both days excluded

also

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  start_date <= '2012-04-12'::date
AND    end_date   >= '2012-01-01'::date;
```

here start_date excluded.

Comment: what type do you have in your start_date and end_date columns?

Comment: timestamp in postgress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  start_date::date <= '2012-04-12'::date
AND    end_date::date   >= '2012-01-01'::date;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  date_trunc('day', start_date) <= '2012-04-12'::date
AND    date_trunc('day', end_date)   >= '2012-01-01'::date;
```

because a timestamp has minutes, seconds... values, which "exclude" your datas.

Casting `start_date` and `end_date` to a `date` type (or using `date_trunc` function) should also work with `OVERLAPS`.

```
SELECT *
   FROM mytable
  WHERE (start_date::date, end_date::date) OVERLAPS ('2012-01-01'::DATE, '2012-04-12'::DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `end_date + 1 day` and `<` instead of `<=`

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  start_date < '2012-04-13'::timestamp
AND    end_date   >= '2012-01-01'::timestamp;
```

I think it should perform better than casting data in you table to `date`